# Add space between button

Tags: react-native

I wanted to add space between button but it's not working below is my code. What do I need to add in my code?

```js
render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <Button style={styles.button}
                title='Add '
            />
            <Button style={styles.button}
                title='Search/Update'
            />
        </View>


    )
}

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        padding: 30
    },
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way is to add a spacing view between your two buttons:

```
<View>
  <Text>Home</Text>
  <Button style={styles.button} title='Add' />
  <View style={styles.space} /> // <------------------------- right here
  <Button style={styles.button} title='Search/Update' />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 30
  },
  space: {
    width: 20, // or whatever size you need
    height: 20,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use like this:

```js
<View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 10 }}>
      <Button title="Add" />
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button title="Search/Update"  />
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this styling to View component in order to get space between two buttons.

Also import `Dimensions` from react-native and adjust the width of View according to your need.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

```
<View style={{
    width:Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.5,
    display:"flex",
    justifyContent:"space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center"

}}>
  <Text>Home</Text>
  <Button 
      style={styles.button}
      title='Add '
  />

  <Button 
      style={styles.button}
      title='Search/Update'
   />
</View>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.DImension.get')

Comment: I have edited the post. It was typo Dimensions instead of Dimension

Comment: Still no space between buttons

Comment: add flex:1 to view style

Answer (score 0):

The code **<View style={{marginVertical: 10}}**   You have to use here.
The Button should come inside View Tag
You can use the below code to add space between button

```
<View style={{marginVertical: 10}}>
  <Button  title="Button 1" />
</View>
<View style={{marginVertical: 10}}>
  <Button  title="Button 2" />
</View>
```

[image]